# Send ViewModel data and Dictionary with an Ajax call

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, dictionary, asp.net-core

Morning,

Today I am having an issue with sending data back to my Controller in MVC (ASP.NET Core, C#).

Essentially I have an Ajax call:

```
function PostEmailList() {
    var finalData = {};
    var x = document.getElementById("CsvSelectIn");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        finalData['myDictionary[' + i + '].Key'] = x.options[i].text;
        finalData['myDictionary[' + i + '].Value'] = parseInt(x.options[i].value);
    }
    finalData['Email'] = $("#textBoxEmail").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'FormSubmit',
        type: 'POST',
        data: finalData,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#EmailList").html($("#EmailList").html() + data);
        }
    })
    return false;
```

This call sorts a list of select options into a dictionary and sends them to the controller. It also sends an email address.

The Controller receives it like this:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult FormSubmit(String Email, Dictionary<string, int?> myDictionary)
        {
            FileUploadDetailView viewModel = new FileUploadDetailView();
            viewModel.Email = Email;
            viewModel.arrayPositions = myDictionary;
            return PartialView("EmailList", viewModel);
        }
```

The parameters come in perfectly.

However, as you can see they then have to be manually applied to the `ViewModel`. I can't seem to find a way to pass a dictionary back to the `viewmodel` regardless. However, I also can't seem to find a way to pass `ViewModel` data back with the dictionary as a separate parameter.

If I was to send data as such:

```
function PostEmailList() {
    var finalData = {};
    var x = document.getElementById("CsvSelectIn");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        finalData['myDictionary[' + i + '].Key'] = x.options[i].text;
        finalData['myDictionary[' + i + '].Value'] = parseInt(x.options[i].value);
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: 'FormSubmit',
        type: 'POST',
        data: 
        {
            Email: $("#textBoxEmail").val(),
            finalData
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#EmailList").html($("#EmailList").html() + data);
        }
    })
    return false;
};
```

This has the Email sent, then the dictionary. I can't claim to fully understand how Ajax sends data, but I know this is wrong, as with the following post method it fails to pass the dictionary correctly:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FormSubmit(FileUploadDetailView viewModel, Dictionary<string, int?> myDictionary)
{
    viewModel.arrayPositions = myDictionary;
    return PartialView("EmailList", viewModel);
}
```

This will successfully add the `Email` to the `viewModel` parameter. However the dictionary becomes size 2 with "`Email`" and "`finalData`" as keys with no values.

Is there a way to pass data to the viewModel parameter and also send the dictionary successfully?

Comment: Why are you using a `Dictionary`? Its far easier to have a collection of a model containing 2 properties. And is you have a view model, why are you using a separate parameter for the `Dictionary` instead of binding to the property in the view model?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Unfortunately I've only been using ASP.NET Core, Javascript, MVC, HTML and Ajax as of Monday so I'm still muddling through what does what and how. Not quite sure how binding works, so I can look that up. What do you mean "a collection of a model"? Do you mean an initial model containing a collection of another model?

Comment: Yes, You view models should contain a property which is a collection of another view model that contains 2 properties (one for the `int` and one for the `string`). But to bind to `Dictionary<string, int?> arrayPositions` property of your view model, then it needs to be `'arrayPositions[' + i + '].Key'` etc

Comment: Ahh, I did try that with "finalData['arrayPositions[' + i + '].Key'] = x.options[i].text;" along with "arrayPositions: finalData" in data. But then when taking viewModel as a parameter it will still get the Email (also passed in data), but not the arrayPositions, which remains null.

Comment: Because you need to add the Email to `finalData` and just use `data: finalData`

Comment: That didn't work at first. I realised I had forgotten a {get; set;} for the dictionary and it seems to work perfectly. Thanks!